# Speed Up Distance Calculations

Tags: r, performance

I would like to speed up a distance calculation. I have already put effort into parallelizing it. Unfortunately it still takes longer than an hour.

Basically, the distance between a vector i and j is computed via manhattan distance. The distances between possible values of the vectors is given in the matrix `Vardist`. `Vardist[i[1],j[1]]`  is the distance between the two values `i[1]` and `j[1]`. (the matrix is indexed by characters in `i[1]` and `j[1]` respectively)

There is one more important addition for the distance computation. The distance between vector i and j is the minimum over all manhattan distances between vector i and any possible permutation of vector j. This makes it computationally heavy the way it is programmed.

I have 1000 objects to compare with another. Furthermore each object is a vector of length 5. So there will be 120 permutations for each vector.

```
    distMatrix <- foreach(i = 1:samplesize,
      .combine = cbind,
      .options.snow=opts,
      .packages = c("combinat"))  %dopar%
      {
      # inititalizing matrix
      dist <- rep(0,samplesize)
      # get values on customer i
      ValuesCi <- as.matrix(recodedData[i,])
      # Remove unecessary entries in value distance matrix
      mVardist <- Vardist[ValuesCi,]

      for(j in i:samplesize){
        # distance between vector i and all permutations of vector j is computed
        # minimum of above all distances is taken as distance between vector i and j
        dist[j] <- min(unlist(permn(recodedData[j,], 
                   function(x){ pdist <- 0
                              #nvariables is length of each vector
                              for(i in 1:nvariables){
                              pdist <- pdist + mVardist[i,as.matrix(x)[i]]
                              }
                              return(pdist)}   )))


      }
      dist
      }
```

Any tips or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: How long are your vectors? Probably the next step is to use `Rcpp` for finding the minimum distance among all permutations of `j`...

Comment: Profiling will help you direct your optimisation efforts. For instance using the `profvis` package (embedded in RStudio if you're using it)

Comment: I notice that you use i both in your outer `foreach` loop and also in your anonymous function. This is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh yes, this code is going to take a while. The basic reason is that you use explicit indexing. Even paralellizing will not help.

Okay, there are several option which you can use.

(1) use `base::dist`; give it a matrix and it will compute distances between the rows in the matrix.

(2) use some clustering packages, e.g. `flexClust`, that has some other options.

(3) If you need to compute distances between rows of a matix with rows of some other matrix, you can vectorize the code, e.g. euclidean distance:

```
function(xmat, ymat) {
  t(apply(xmat, 1, function(x) {
    sqrt(colSums((t(ymat) - x)^2))
  }))
}
```

(4) use *C++* and `Rcpp` to make use of the *BLAS* functionality and you may even consider parallelizing code using [RcppParallel (distance matrix example)](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/parallel-distance-matrix/)

When you have fast routines for middle-sized data, then you may go into distributing it to clusters ... for large data.